# how to open another php file from the php file that was invoked with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to open php file using ajax:

`xhttp.open("login.php?login=me)`

I want PHP file that was called by ajax open another PHP file instead of responseText.
 here the code:

**`<?php if($_GET['login']==="me"){
   header("location: home.php");
}else echo "wrong name";`**

the above code will work like what I want when called directly via the url, but if it called by ajax the home.php file is returned as responseText.
**note: I don't want to redirect use client side**
ps: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in php on ajax request . You have to do this in javascript After AJAX response just like

```
 window.open("home.php","_self")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($_GET['login']==="me"){
   echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'url' => 'home.php'));
}else {
  echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'wrong name'));
```

and in your javascript read json (`JSON.parse(response)`) and write something like:

`var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
if (responseObj.success) {
    window.location.href = responseObj.url;
} else {
    alert("Error occurred: " + responseObj.error);
}`